# Hidden fields web form cookies

Tags: html, cookies

I need help answering this question: *Hidden fields in web forms can be used to simulate:*

1. httpOnly persistent cookie
2. httpOnly session cookie
3. persistent cookie
4. session cookie

Thanks.

Comment: Can the people who downvoted please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 2. httpOnly session cookie.